# JavaSound: Extract one channel of stereo audio

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I have a stereo wave file that I need to read and play back only the selected channel. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you bring the wav file in via an AudioInputStream, use the AudioFileFormat info to convert the bytes to PCM. The data for the right and left alternates. So, if the line is 16-bit, you will have 4 bytes per frame. The first two will be assembled into the left channel and the second two will be assembled into the right channel. (Or vice versa--I have trouble keeping straight in my mind which channel is left or right.)

Here's a good tutorial with example on how to read a line:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html

Some of the earlier tutorials in the trail might be needed to help clarify. Also, if you have questions about converting bytes to PCM and back, there are several explanations already on StackOverflow to reference. Should not be too hard to find them.

Comment: Thanks Phil! Checking the tutorial now.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'convert to DSP"?

Comment: That was a mental hair ball on my part. I should have said PCM!! Sorry about that. I corrected the original post.

Comment: bytes 0 and 1 in the 4 byte frame were the left channel. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method to extract single channels from a multi channel direct audio line (JavaSound). In tried it with my Line6(r) Helix(r) guitar sound effect board (8 channels) and it works pretty fine. I guess it works with any kind of DataTargetLine. In this case we process data based on an AudioFormat bearing 16 bits samples. Hope it helps.

```
    public ArrayList<byte[]> extract16BitsSingleChannels(byte[] audioBuffer, int channels) {

    /* Parameters :
     * 
     * audioBuffer : the buffer that has just been produced by
     * your targetDataLine.read();
     * channels : the number of channels defined in the AudioFormat you 
     * use with the line
     * 
     *  the AudioFormat which I tested :
     *       float sampleRate = 44100; 
     *       int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
     *       int channels = 8;
     *       boolean signed = true;
     *       boolean bigEndian = true;
     */


    /* let's create a container which will receive our "per channel" buffers */

    ArrayList<byte[]> channelsData = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

    /* take care of adjusting the size of the audioBuffer so that 
     * audioBuffer % channels == 0 is true ... because :        
     */

    final int channelLength=audioBuffer.length/channels;

    /* let's create one buffer per channel and place them in the
     * container 
     */

    for (int c=0 ; c < channels ; c++) 

    {
        byte[] channel=new byte[channelLength];
        channelsData.add(channel);
    }

    /* then process bytes from audioBuffer and copy each channels byte 
     * in its dedicated buffer 
     */

    int byteIndex=0; 

    for(int i = 0; i < channelLength; i+=2) //i+=2 for 16 bits=2 Bytes samples
    {
        for (int c=0 ; c < channels ; c++) {
            channelsData.get(c)[i]=audioBuffer[byteIndex];   // 1st Byte
            byteIndex++;
            channelsData.get(c)[i+1]=audioBuffer[byteIndex]; // 2nd Byte
            byteIndex++;
        }

    }

    /* Returns each set of bytes from each channel in its buffer you can use to
       write on whatever Byte streamer you like. */

    return channelsData;   

}
```