# Java Audio - Process 2 channels

Tags: java, audio, channel

ive followed some tutorials about how to capture stereo audio in Java.
Its looks like very simple, just set the channel to 2 and its done.

```
AudioFormat.Encoding encoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;
float rate = 44100.0f;
int channels = 2;
int frameSize = 4;
int sampleSize = 16;
boolean bigEndian = true;

AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(encoding, rate, sampleSize, channels, (sampleSize / 8)
          * channels, rate, bigEndian);

DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
```

But now i want to process the data of each channel independently.
The problem is, the tutorial shown that the data was represented as byte array.

How do i know, which data belongs to which channel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaSound: Extract one channel of stereo audio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776803/javasound-extract-one-channel-of-stereo-audio)

Comment: thanks @greg-449.. its hard for me to find the correct keyword before posting this question..